# Locked out of my own MySQL Database

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I logged into my SQL server today using PhpMyAdmin, and it seems to be acting weird throwing random [Token Mismatch] errors, only while trying to create a new user account. I tried multiple times, with multiple users, and still got the same thing. I then tried to update my own password, which succeed, however, does not allow me to log into the server.

Trying to login with myusername, and the newly set password returns the following error in PhpMyAdmin.

```
#1130 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I have command line access to the server, and tried logging into my 'root' user, which I am getting this:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I know, with 100% certainty, that I am entering in both my user account password, and root password correctly, but am not able to log into the server.

This is a production server, and has multiple hosted websites running from it.

I have tried running

```
mysqladmin -u root password my-new-pass
```

But, not knowing the root password that already exists, this fails.

I am completely locked out of my own database on all administrative accounts, how would one go about regaining access to the database, while retaining all of the data in the database?

If any additional information, or diagnostic steps are require, please do not hesitate to ask. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure mysql is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can restart mysql, you can reset your root password.

```
service mysql stop

mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

mysql -u root

use mysql;

update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';

flush privileges;

quit

service mysql restart
```

You should now be able to log in

Comment: Much love. Worked perfect. The problems seems to be that my old user got removed from the system, and I access the database remotely, with the root user only allowed local login. Thanks again.